# How to use REGEXP in MySQL to aquire specific columns

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

Recently I tried without successes asking MySQL DB for specific data:

```
SELECT code, txt_gb, txt_de 
FROM table 
WHERE code REGEXP 'chol'
OR txt_gb REGEXP 'chol' 
OR txt_de REGEXP 'chol' 
ORDER BY code 
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

I read somewhere that LIKE command has better performance that REGEXP. Is it true? Can I use LIKE in this case instead of REGEXP to find a part of cell?
I am very interested in minimizing the load on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT code, txt_gb, txt_de FROM table WHERE code like '%chol%' OR txt_gb like '%chol%' OR txt_de like '%chol%' ORDER BY code
```

yes Regex is slow at time, like is not faster even, but works well and easy to write then regex for your need.